# File Upload / Strange Permissions Issue

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7

I have a site that's been running for a while.  All was going well.  Until now.  Dun duunnn dunnnnn.

I am unable to upload from an attachment field to a particular directory.  But I can upload to that directory.

Desired directory to upload (does not work):

```
/sites/default/files/resources/case-studies
4 drwxrwxrwx  2 apache   apache    4096 Jul 22  2013 case-studies
```

Uploading DOES work to the parent directory:

```
/sites/default/files/resources
4 drwxrwxrwx 10 apache   apache    4096 Mar 18 10:15 resources
```

As far as I can tell they are identically permissioned.  Is there something I am missing?

Thanks, hive mind!

steve

Comment: For reasons I haven't figured out, this works:

    chmod -R a+w files   <----- yay!

This make sense to me, but I really can't figure out why that would work and not :

    chmod -R 777 files   <----- boo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons I haven't figured out, this works: chmod -R a+w files <----- yay! This make sense to me, but I really can't figure out why that would work and not : chmod -R 777 files <----- boo!